# What's $k$ in the wave equation (Quantum Tunneling)?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, momentum, wavefunction, notation

Given the wave function $\psi(x)= A_1\,e^{i\,k\,x} + A_2\,e^{-i\,k\,x}$ that describes a wave being transmitted and reflected on a potential barrier. In this context I find different notations for $k$:

At first it's described as $k = \frac{\sqrt{2\,m\,E}}{\hbar}$, secondly as $k = \frac{p}{h}$. Are these things the same - and what are they actually? Is k a kind of 'decay konstant' or is it even being the wave vector?

Lastly: Is there a way to describe the komplex wave function with terms of sine? E.g. $\psi(x) = \sin(k\,x)$

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it lacks elementary research.

Comment: The wave function can be expressed in terms of sine functions and exponential functions instead of complex exponentials.  In fact it's clearer to see the boundary matching conditions if you do.

Answer (score 1):

Yes they are same. (It is $ p/\hbar$)